# Не получается запустить Jupyter в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Не получается заставить работать Jupyter в PyCharm. Дома все впорядке, запускается, а на работе выдает такую ошибку. Подскажите, что нужно сделать, кто знает. Гуглил, разобраться не смог. Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py" notebook --no-browser --ip 127.0.0.1:8888 --port 8888 --port-retries=0
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 869, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '127.0.0.1:8888' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(f())
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 119, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-110>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 300, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 446, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 295, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 514, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 236, in initialize_subcommand
    return super(BaseIPythonApplication, self).initialize_subcommand(subc, argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 452, in initialize_subcommand
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-114>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 251, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\PycharmProjects\srochnoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 872, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\kozlovs01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильно задан аргумент ip. Вместо `--ip 127.0.0.1:8888` должно быть `--ip 127.0.0.1`. Изменить это можно в настройках run configuration.